# Finding product of odds in an array recursively

Tags: java, recursion

This is the original problem:

Write a recursive, int valued method named `productOfOdds` that accepts an integer array and the number of elements in the array, and returns the product of the odd-valued elements of the array. You may assume the array has at least one odd-valued element. The product of the odd-valued elements of an integer-valued array recursively may be calculated as follows:

- If the array has a single element and it is odd, return the value of that element; otherwise return 1.
- Otherwise, if the first element of the array is odd, return the product of that element and the result of finding the product of the odd elements of the rest of the array; if the first element is NOT odd, simply return the result of finding the product of the odd elements of the rest of the array.

This is what I have and I can't figure out why it's not working:

```
public static int productOfOdds(int[] arr, int index)
{
    if (index == 1) 
    { 
        if ((arr[0]%2) != 0)  
            return arr[0]; 
        else 
            return 1; 
    }
    else if ((arr[0] % 2) != 0)           
        return (arr[0] * productOfOdds(arr, index - 1));            
    else
        return productOfOdds(arr, index - 1);
}
```

Comment: what calls this function in your main?

Comment: The problem is you don't remove elements from the array, if the array is `[1, 2, 3]`, you should return `1 * productOfOdds([2,3], index - 1)`, no?

Comment: i was only concerned with writing the function and not with calling the function in main. yes you were right. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, while you pass in your index, you don't check the array value at your index, but the array value at 0.  This should fix the problem:

```
public static int productOfOdds(int[] arr, int index){
    if (index == 1) 
    { 
        if ((arr[index-1]%2) != 0)  
             return arr[index-1]; 
        else 
             return 1; 

    }

    else if((arr[index-1]%2) != 0 )           
         return (arr[index-1] * productOfOdds(arr, index-1));            
    else
         return productOfOdds(arr, index-1);            
}
```

Comment: you're right, my array was stuck in one place. Thank you.

Comment: Although it is the answer but I think its wrong, because you didnt remove elements from the array. suppose the end state that you have just one element in the array, but you pass an array with lots of element to the function.

Comment: @AliAmiri yes, that would be better, but this demonstrates the problem with the code.  Changing it more drastically, which I considered, might confuse Eternal Punishment

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this part:

```
else if ((arr[0] % 2) != 0) 
    return (arr[0] * productOfOdds(arr, index - 1));
```

You meant to say:

```
else if ((arr[index] % 2) != 0) 
    return (arr[index] * productOfOdds(arr, index - 1));
```

By using `0` here instead of `index` your result will always be

- `1` if `arr[0]` is even
- `arr[0]` if it is odd

Comment: no i kind of mislabeled that parameter but index = the number of elements in the array. when i make the changes you suggested i get an out of bounds error. thanks for your reply though

Comment: @user4279775 You are getting an array out of bounds exception because you are calling this method initially with `productOfOdds(arr, arr.length)`. If you instead use `productOfOdds(arr, arr.length - 1)`, then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is that you never calculate anything that's not the first array element. There is nothing in your recursion that causes it to go to the second element, the third and so on.

What may be confusing is the fact the parameter that expresses the *length* of the array is called `index`. But you're treating it like length. Anyway, let's see what you are doing here:

Your end condition seems good - if the *length* is 1, test the only element that exists, and do as the assignment text tells you to do.

But what about the recursion step?

Suppose you have two elements and the first one is odd. Your `index` is 2. So you call the same function with the same array and `1`. This will return the value of the element in position zero. And then you multiply it by the element at position zero. If your array was 8 elements long, it would still be multiplying by the same first element, so you basically get (arr[0])<sup>length</sup> (if it's odd) or 1 (if it's not odd).

You have two ways to solve this problem.

**Go with only one parameter, but against the text of the assignment**

To do this, you have to check the *last* element of the array. So if your array length 1, you do as you did so far. But if it's greater than 1, you have to do:

```
if ( arr[index-1]%2 != 0 ) {
    return arr[index-1]*productOfOdds(arr,index-1);
} else {
    return productOfOdds(arr,index-1);
}
```

**Go with two parameters, but follow the letter of the assignment**

To do this, you have to also pass the parameter that says where the subarray starts. That is, you check the first element of the array, but tell the recursive step to check from the second element forward. Basically, you tell your method "Look at this array as if it's starting at position `startIndex` rather than `0`".

```
private static int productOfOdds(int[] arr, int startIndex, int length) {
    if (length == 1)  { 
        if ((arr[startIndex]%2) != 0)  
            return arr[startIndex]; 
        else 
            return 1; 

    } else if((arr[startIndex]%2) != 0 )           
         return (arr[startIndex] * productOfOdds(arr, startIndex + 1, length-1));            
    else
         return productOfOdds(arr, startIndex+1, length-1));            
}

public static int productOfOdds(int[] arr, int length ) {
    return productOfOdds( arr, 0, length );
}
```

The second method with just two parameters is there in order to follow the letter of your assignment, which was to have a method that accepts an array and its length only. Internally it works with three parameters, but to the world you present a two-parameter method (note the `private` vs `public` modifiers).

Personally, I think the first method is more elegant, despite the fact that your instructor told you to use the first element.